# Insert data from database to table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to insert data from database to table.
I am able to get data from database and insert that into table,but only the last data is inserted in all rows of table. I have used the code as

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
     Action *actionInformation;

    if(cell == nil){


        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];

        PrepopulatedActionsDao * preAction = [[PrepopulatedActionsDao alloc] init];

        [preAction getDataFromDatabase];

        NSMutableArray *allPreActions=[preAction getDataFromDatabase];

        for(int i=0;i<[allPreActions count];i++){

            actionInformation=[allPreActions objectAtIndex:i];


            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",actionInformation.action];

        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Here PrepopulatedActionsDao is the class where I am getting all datas from database.

I want to insert all datas of database in table not only the last one.
please anybody help.

Comment: what is the value in numberOfRowsInSection of uitableview class??

Comment: @Sarah : Its 100 as data in database is 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of the for loop. The `cellforrow` method is called for every row in the tableview. So u just need to put the following line `cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[[allPreActions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] action];` instead of the for loop.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called for each row, so you need to provide the correct data in each call. So, instead of the "for loop", you can do

```
actionInformation=[allPreActions objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",actionInformation.action];
```

You may also want to cache allPreActions instead of filling it in each call.

Answer (score 0):

This gets allocated every time. So declare it outside.

```
PrepopulatedActionsDao * preAction = [[PrepopulatedActionsDao alloc] init];

[preAction getDataFromDatabase];
  NSMutableArray *allPreActions=[preAction getDataFromDatabase];
```

Also you don't need for loop, Instead do it in this manner :

```
    actionInformation=[allPreActions objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",actionInformation.action];
```

Comment: Also retain the NSMutableArray after allPreActions=[preAction getDataFromDatabase];

Answer (score 0):

Declare `NSMutableArray` member `allPreActions` in .h file (Declare it as a class member) and populate it in `viewDidLoad` or somewhere else before `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

So this code will come in `viewDidLoad`

```
PrepopulatedActionsDao * preAction = [[PrepopulatedActionsDao alloc] init];

if( allPreActions )
{
   [allPreActions releaseAllObjects];
   [allPreActions release];
}

allPreActions = [[preAction getDataFromDatabase] retain];
[preAction release];
```

And your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will look like as follows

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    Action *actionInformation;

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];
    }
    actionInformation=[allPreActions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",actionInformation.action];

    return cell;
}
```